# Chossing xtype using if else

Tags: extjs

I'm trying out new things in extjs and i want to choose xtype depending on value that is sent from database. The value is boolean. So when it is false i want that xtype to be hidden, and when it is true to be button.

Something like this:

```
if (valuefield == false){
    xtype: 'hidden'
}
else{
   xtype: 'button'
}
```

i know that the value field contains false or true, but when if else is add than the error pops up, how to make it work with if else statement??

this is my code:

text: 'Admin',

```
xtype: 'button',                                    
href: 'admin',
hrefTarget: '_self',                

queryMode : 'local',

valueField: 'admin',
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
{
 fields: ['admin'],
autoLoad: true,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'admin/premision',
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an inline if:

```
xtype: valueField ? 'button' : 'hidden'
```

Although it would probably be preferable to set the hidden property instead:

```
xtype: 'button',
hidden: valueField ? false : true
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this fiddle you give you some idea - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lho

```
    Ext.application({
    name : 'Test Dynamic Xtype', 
    launch : function() {

        Ext.define('HiddenModel',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                'hidden', Boolean
            ]
        });
        // create the Data Store - This is a memory store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'HiddenModel',
            //autoLoad: true,
            data:[{'hidden': false}]
        });

        // function that returns the xtype as string based on hidden: true| false
        var type = function getType(hidden){
            if(hidden)
                return 'textarea'
            else
                return 'textfield'
        }

        Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
            title      : 'Test Item Click',
            width      : 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: type(store.getData().items[0].data.hidden), // 
                text: 'My Field',
                name: 'My Field',
                value:'Hello'

            }]
        });

    }
});
```